# line breaks not allowed in string literals while debugging

Tags: webservices, error

I got this error line breaks not allowed in string literals while debugging. Please help !

```
    String clientId = 'AKIAJGN4J4RSRNW26IEA';
    String clientSecret = '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';
    String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&username='username'&password='password';

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqbody);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://s3.amazonaws.com/ashu1197/demo%203');

    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    system.debug('--------'+res.getBody());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing means a string has been split over several lines in the editor. However in this case it's because you've not joined strings together properly with variables in this line:

```
String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&username='username'&password='password';
```

You need to use the `+` operator to join the string parts and variables:

```
String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
```

That might look a little confusing in here, but with the syntax highlighting in your editor it should be more obvious. I doubt it applies in this case, but if you need an apostrophe inside of a string you can escape it with a backslash:

```
String s = 'Matt\'s String';
```

Comment: Thanks Lacey for the detailed explanation . I'm getting an error which I'm trying since hours . The error is CALLOUT_RESPONSE [11]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405] . Or should i post new question . Thanks again .

Comment: Yep, that's a candidate for a new question. But essentially ou have to set a header for the method type, which I think defaults to 'GET' and it sounds like the server isn't expecting that. There's a good chance it's expecting 'POST'.